# Obtaining childNodes from this xml

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, nodes

I am trying to extract the childnodes using XML.XMLNode as currently I am using the following code to get my value information.

```
Dim objXML As New Xml.XmlDocument
Dim colNode As Xml.XmlNode
Dim rowNode As Xml.XmlNode
Dim RespNode As Xml.XmlNode

For Each RespNode In objXML.ChildNodes
            For Each rowNode In RespNode.ChildNodes
                For Each colNode In rowNode.ChildNodes
testStr = colNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value
Next
Next
Next
```

How can I get the fieldPasswordValue: 1234 and fieldPasswordValue: 4567 by modifying the code I'm currently using?

**XML:**

```
 <resp status="ok">
       <data id="41170">
        <field name="abc">xyz</field>
          <composite>
             <data id="51253">
                <field name="fieldPasswordValue"/>1234</field>
            </data>
             <data id="52356">
                <field name="fieldPasswordValue"/>4567</field>
           </data>
    </composite>
    </data>
    </resp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your xml is wrong. You are closing the field twice by doing

```
<field name="fieldPasswordValue"/>1234</field>
```

It should be

```
<field name="fieldPasswordValue">1234</field>
```

To get the value, you can search the xml using xpath.

```
For Each node As Xml.XmlNode In objXML.SelectNodes("//field[@name='fieldPasswordValue']")
     Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText)
Next
```

I suggest you [read up on the syntax of xpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471(v=vs.110).aspx) to get exactly what you are looing for. You could even remove your 3 for loops in your sample.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was a typo. The field isn't closed twice. Instead of using the SelectNodes, can I not loop through all of them under the composite tag? Say I have two data nodes like the one above and each data node has 'n' number of field nodes. How can I get to all of the field nodes and loop through them?

Comment: You could use the ParentNode to get the data or use xpath to find all data under composite and then an other call to find all fields under.